# How to schedule a cron job every 4 hour 48 minutes?

Tags: linux, cron, cron-task

Do I have to write 5 cronjobs for this?

The only other thing I have in mind is `*/48 */4 ***`, but I don't think that works

Comment: cron is really good at running things at a certain time (eg, the 48th minute of the 4th hour).  It is not so good at running things periodically.  Why do you want to use cron at all for this task?

Comment: Yup, I need to run a python script every 4 hr 48 mins. Is there any alternative to cron?

Comment: There are many alternatives.  It sounds like all you really need is a simple wrapper that does: `while sleep 17280; do python /path/to/script; done`, which will run the script with approximately 4 hours and 48 minutes between the end of one execution and the beginning of the next.  If you want more precision or want to discount the running time of the script, you might want to look at `at`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible only with crontab but you can use a script.
copy and paste the following on a terminal;
obviosuly you need to change the first row by replacing /home/hf/ with an existing folder,
eventually replace myloop.sh with a more meaningful name (optional)
and replacing /path/to/script.sh with the script or command you need to launch

```
export myhome=/home/hf/ ; export loopbat=myloop.sh ; export scripttorun=/path/to/script.sh

echo "COUNTER=0" > ${myhome}${loopbat}
echo "while [  \$COUNTER -lt 5 ]; do" >> ${myhome}${loopbat}
echo "   echo The counter is \$COUNTER" >> ${myhome}${loopbat}
echo "   /bin/bash $scripttorun" >> ${myhome}${loopbat}
echo "   let COUNTER=COUNTER+1" >> ${myhome}${loopbat}
echo "   sleep 17280" >> ${myhome}${loopbat}
echo "done" >> ${myhome}${loopbat}
```

then call the loop script from crontab once per day

```
00 00 * * * /home/hf/myscript.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like that
    `48 */4 * * * echo "bla bla bla" >> /homu/x/Desktop/example.txt >/dev/null 2>&1`
in crontab file or use command of crontab and you can use MAN for understand crontab. If you wont do, I can help you as spesifical.
[For crontab](https://crontab.guru/#48_*/4_*_*_*) this site help what you want

Comment: This will run at 4:48 each day, not every 4 hours and 48 minutes as requested by the OP

Answer (score 0):

You were close in your attempt. Try

```
48 */4 * * *
```